# AuthenticationManager injection failed in spring boot 2.2.2

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to use Spring boot AuthenticationManager class in my web application while doing that i am getting an error that

> **Field authMang in com.tabish.flightreservation.services.SecurityServiceImpl required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' that could not be found.**

and

> **The injection point has the following annotations:
>       - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)**

and it is asking me to do this

> **Action:
>   Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' in your configuration.**

My code is :

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class SecurityServiceImpl implements SecurityService {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailService;

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authMang;

    @Override
    public boolean login(String username, String password) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailService.loadUserByUsername(username);

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password,
                userDetails.getAuthorities());

        authMang.authenticate(token);

        boolean result = token.isAuthenticated();

        //If result is successful then spring will not ask for auth again and again and will not display login page again
        if(result)
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(token);

        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: How have you configured the `AuthenticationManager`?

Comment: how can you do that? can you please explain step by step as i am new to this technology @Ritesh

Comment: You can take a look at tutorials or guides online. For example this one https://springframework.guru/spring-boot-web-application-part-6-spring-security-with-dao-authentication-provider/ may help if you are authenticating a user against a database. Also note that in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` subclass you can expose authentication manager bean as follows: `@Bean @Override
 public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
  return super.authenticationManagerBean();
 }`

Comment: Thanks ritesh for the valuable feedback and i have added those line in my WebSecurityConfigureAdapter and i resolved my error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above by @Ritesh. That's what solved my problem.

```
@Bean 
@Override   
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {          
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();   
}
```